# API to get metrics for HBase regions

Tags: hbase

I'd like to get the region metrics for all the regions on a particular region server.  In particular, I'm after the readRequestsCount and writeRequestsCount.  I see those values in the region server web interface, but I haven't been able to locate the API access to those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [RegionServerMetrics](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/metrics/RegionServerMetrics.html) class. It provides both [readRequestsCount](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/metrics/RegionServerMetrics.html#readRequestsCount) and [writeRequestsCount](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/metrics/RegionServerMetrics.html#writeRequestsCount) methods.

Answer (score 3):

The crux of my solution in Scala:

```
val config = new Configuration()
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", /* put your own entry here */)

val admin = new HBaseAdmin(config)
val master = admin.getMaster
val servers = master.getClusterStatus.getServers

for(server <- servers){
  val load = master.getClusterStatus.getLoad(server)
  val rloads = load.getRegionsLoad
  for ((k,rload) <- rloads){

    // Do whatever you please with these values
    var region = Bytes.toString(k)
    val host = server.getHostname
    val reads = rload.getReadRequestsCount
    val writes = rload.getWriteRequestsCount
  }
}
```